# Receiving a list index out of range error when returning soup.select

Tags: python-3.x

Attempting to scrape a price from an amazon page but I'm getting a list index out of range error with `return elems[0].text.strip()`

How do I test the `len` of the `soup.select` parameter?

Here's the code:

```
def getAmazonPrice(productUrl):
    res = requests.get(productUrl, headers={
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
})
    res.raise_for_status()

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    elems = soup.select('#buyNewSection > a > h5 > div > div.a-column.a-span8.a-text-right.a-span-last > div > span.a-size-medium.a-color-price.offer-price.a-text-normal')
    return elems[0].text.strip()

price = getAmazonPrice('https://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-2nd/dp/1593279922/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=automate+the+boring+stuff+with+python&qid=1574259797&sr=8-1')
print('The price is ' + price)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/xxx/Documents/MyPythonScripts/scrape.py", line 14, in 
>       price = getAmazonPrice('[https://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-2nd/dp/1593279922/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=automate+the+boring+stuff+with+python&qid=1574259797&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593279922)')
>     File "/Users/xxx/Documents/MyPythonScripts/scrape.py", line 12, in getAmazonPrice
>       return elems[0].text.strip()
>   IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

Test `elems` before indexing it:

```
if elems:  # Or if len(elems) > 0:
    return elems[0].text.strip()

else:
    # Handle failure
```